# Fazer alert aparecer apenas quando a pagina já estiver carregada

Tags: javascript, alert

Eu tenho um formulário que envia os dados pra mesma pagina de onde o usuário os digitou pelo método POST e faço que na URL seja criada uma variável por GET para acionar um alert por JS que tenho em meu codigo, o intuito desse código quando a pagina é recarregada é que ele exiba a mensagem para o usuário dizendo que o formulário foi enviado com sucesso!
 
 
  No entanto, ele acaba exibindo o alert antes mesmo do conteudo da pagina ser carregado, e fica feio só aquele alert, sendo que o resto da pagina só vai carregar após clicar no OK, existe alguma forma de fazer o Alert exibir a mensagem só quando a pagina for recarregada?

Comment: Oi Vinicius da pra partilhar um pouco do codigo pra entendermos melhor a situacao e tentar ajudar de forma mais eficiente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma das formas é colocar seu alert dentro de um setTimeout com time 0.

```js
  setTimeout(function(){
        alert('com setTimeout');
   },0);
```

```html
<h1> texto do site <h2>
```